# store non english text into sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, unicode

i want to store unicode data into my database.actually it a 4 line verses of text in sanskrit.coz i am new to db programming ,i don't know how to store my language in to db.i   have read some info in forums ,yet i am not clear in storing my data into db 
hope someone will help me out here 
thanks in advance 
baran

Comment: How do you create or open sqlite database? (UTF-8 or UTF-16)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the sqlite C API, then ensure that the data is in either UTF-8 or UTF-16 format and then bind it using either the sqlite_bind_text or sqlite_bind_text16.

See http://sqlite.org/cintro.html for intro to using the API. Specifically "1.1 Typical Usage Of Core Routines And Objects". See http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html for the function reference.

For example, something like:

```
const char sql[] = "INSERT INTO table (mytext) VALUES (?, ?);";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, myutf8text, -1, NULL)
sqlite3_step(stmt)
sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
```

Comment: hi  brofield , thanks a lot for you reply.. i ll give it a try & reply back you back again .

Answer (score 1):

If you create your database using `sqlite3_open` then it is UTF-8 encoded, or if you use `sqlite3_open16` to create then it is UTF-16 encoded. It is the first point that you should care.

And, if you trying to write UTF-8 encoded string to UTF-16 encoded database, you will need a simple MBCS to UNICODE converter. or vice versa. Then the answer of brofield is valid.